# Oracle 11g insert into select from a table with duplicate rows

Tags: oracle, duplicates, sql-insert

I have one table that need to split into several other tables.
But the main table is just like a transitive table.
I dump data from a excel into it (from 5k to 200k rows) , and using insert into select, split into the correct tables (Five different tables).
However, the latest dataset that my client sent has records with duplicates values.

The primary key usually is ENI for my table. But even this record is duplicated because the same company can be a customer and a service provider, so they have two different registers but use the same ENI.

What i have so far.
I found a script that uses merge and modified it to find same eni and update the same main_id to all

```
|Main_id|   ENI     |   company_name|   Type
|   1   |   1864    |   JOHN        |   C
|   2   |   351485  |   JOEL        |   C
|   3   |   16546   |   MICHEL      |   C
|   2   |   351485  |   JOEL J.     |   S
|   1   |   1864    |   JOHN E. E.  |   C

Main_id: Primarykey that the main BD uses
ENI: Unique company number
Type: 'C' - COSTUMER 'S' - SERVICE PROVIDERR
```

Some Cases it can have the same type. just like id 1
there are several other Columns...

What i need:
insert any of the main_id my other script already sorted, and set a flag on the others that they were not inserted. i cant delete any data i'll need to send these info to the costumer validate.

or i just simply cant make this way and go back to the good old excel

Edit: as a question below this is a example

```
|Main_id|   ENI     |   company_name|   Type|   RANK|
|   1   |   1864    |   JOHN        |   C   |   1   |
|   2   |   351485  |   JOEL        |   C   |   1   |
|   3   |   16546   |   MICHEL      |   C   |   1   |
|   2   |   351485  |   JOEL J.     |   S   |   2   |
|   1   |   1864    |   JOHN E. E.  |   C   |   2   |

    RANK -  would be like the 1864 appears 2 times,
1st one found gets 1 second 2 and so on. i tryed using
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MAIN_ID ORDER BY ENI)
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY company_name ORDER BY ENI)
```

**Thanks to TEJASH i was able to come up with this solution**

```
MERGE INTO TABLEA S
    USING (Select ROWID AS ID,
        row_number() Over(partition by eniorder by eni, type) as RANK_DUPLICATED
        From TABLEA
    ) T
    ON (S.ROWID = T.ID)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET S.RANK_DUPLICATED= T.RANK_DUPLICATED;
```

Comment: Are you inserting bulk or one-by-one. You can do insert; and then select with left join to find records that are not inserted because they exist in source but not in target

Comment: `INSERT INTO TABLE_B (MAIN_ID, ENI, COMPANY_NAME)`
`SELECT MAIN_ID, ENI, MAX(COMPANY_NAME) FROM TABLE_A`
`GROUP BY MAIN_ID, ENI`

in this table this works but i cant do this to the other tables because it can get column a from row 1 and column b from row 5

Comment: Looks like in one case company can be both a customer or service provider. and in other case both main_id and type are same except extra characters in company name.What's the business rule to insert

Comment: I tried using RANK to enumarate all the duplicates, but with no success, if i could do this i can ust use where rank = 1 but no idea how

Comment: Can you please share the expected output?

Comment: I edited the main post to give an ex.

Comment: Ok, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood your problem, you just need to know the duplicate based on 2 columns. You can achieve it using analytical function as follows:

```
Select t.*, 
       row_number() Over(partition by main_id, eni order by company_name) as rnk
  From your_table t
```

Comment: Yep that solved it.
i knew ROWNUM,but did not know this row_number().